# Как разделить на группы и посчитать сумму в группах sql

Tags: sql

Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть следующая. Таблица отсортирована по id. Нужно сгруппировать по столбцу group1 и group2, посчитать сумму в столбце razn следующим образом - группы в столбце group2 находятся между нулями. То есть в итоге должно получиться что-то вроде такой таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой именно sql ? такие штуки лучше делать оконными функциями и очень хотелось бы что бы ваша БД поддерживала их

Comment: Да, поддерживает

Comment: Все таки отредактируйте вопрос и в метках поставьте конкретную СУБД которая используется. А еще данные в виде create table/insert прямо в вопросе приведите. Ну или на крайний случай в виде таблицы, но текстом. Запрос я могу написать, но вот перебивать с картинки ваши данные для теста себе я не буду

Comment: А так, общая идея: сделать что то вроде `case when lead(group2) over(partition by group1 order by id)!=group2 then 1 else 0 end X`, обернуть внешним запросом, в нем `sum(X) over(partition by group1 order by id) grp` получим номера групп, которые меняются на нужных разделах, ну там может +- подправить, смотря что вышло. И потом по этому grp уже можно группировать как обычно group by

Comment: Сумма должна быть по столбцу razn. Чуть позже отредактирую, добавлю таблицу

Comment: ну sum сами допишете во внешнем запросе вместе с group by, я только дал наброски как формировать номера групп, по которым group by потом отработать сможет

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab as (
select
id
,group1
,group2
    case when (lead([group2]) over(Partition by group1 order by id) = 0) or (lead([group2]) over(Partition by group1 order by id) is null) then id else null end as current_id
)
Select 
t1.*
,z.current_id
from tab t1
outer apply
(
Select top 1 t2.current_id
from tab t2
where t1.group1  = t2.group1  and t1.id<=t2.id and t2.current_id is not null
order by t2.id
)z
```

И остаётся все это безобразие сгруппировать по t1.group1 , z.current_id и посчитать сумму